# How to spread some objects on the whole screen

Tags: python, pygame

I am learning to code in pygame. And there is task to spread stars onto the whole screen.

I've done my code, but it spreads stars only on the left top angle of the screen and I don't really know how to place stars on the whole screen. This code answer for the spreading:

```
def x_demension(custom_settings, star):
    available_x = custom_settings.width - 2*star.rect.width #available space along abscissa axis
    count_numbers = int(available_x / (2*star.rect.width)) #quantity of stars throught weight
    return count_numbers


def y_demension(custom_settings, star, spaceship):
    available_y = custom_settings.height - 2*star.rect.height - spaceship.rect.height #available space along ordinate axis
    number_rows = int(available_y / (2*star.rect.height)) #quantity of rows throught height
    return number_rows


def create_star(screen, custom_settings, number, row_number, stars):
    star = Star(screen, custom_settings) #create an instance of a star

    star.rect.x = star.rect.width + 2*star.rect.width * randint(0,number) #coordinate x of a star
    x = randint(0, star.rect.x)
    star.rect.x = x

    star.rect.y = star.rect.height + 2*star.rect.height * randint(0,row_number) #coordinate y of a star
    y = randint(0,star.rect.y)
    star.rect.y = y

    stars.add(star) #added stars
    if len(stars) > 50: #limiter of the star adding
        stars.remove(star)
    else:
        stars.add(star)


def starsky(custom_settings, screen, spaceship, stars):
    star = Star(custom_settings, screen) #created as an instance of a random star
    number_stars = x_demension(custom_settings, star)
    number_rows = y_demension(custom_settings, star, spaceship)
    for row_number in range(number_rows):
        for number in range(number_stars):
            create_star(screen, custom_settings, number, row_number, stars)
```

[This is what I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSKZG.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, shouldn't it just be:

```
def create_star(screen, custom_settings, number, row_number, stars):
    star = Star(screen, custom_settings)
    w, h = pygame.display.get_surface().get_size()
    x = randint(0, w)
    star.rect.x = x
    y = randint(0, h)
    star.rect.y = y

    stars.add(star) #added stars
    if len(stars) > 50: #limiter of the star adding
        stars.remove(star)
    else:
        stars.add(star)
```

Comment: You are still limiting the stars to the top left, in a square equal to width and height of the star. `randint` should be allowed to generate numbers from 0 up to the width or height of the screen to span stars on the whole screen.